# Doesn't damage occuring in the damage phase occur simultaneously?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, magic-duels

I was playing MtG Duels and was up against an opponent who had me down to 2 life.  They had a [Perilous Myr](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194056) so when it died would deal damage to me - sufficient to kill me.
I had a [Juggernaut](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383289) down so was forced to attack, so decided to just attack with everything to see what the rule was (or the game thought the rule was).  I had sufficient damage to kill them regardless of what they blocked.
I was pretty sure it would be a draw (dying/damage at the same time) or loss (their Myr's death would kill me before my attackers did damage) but despite their block and the Myr dying, I was granted the win.

Was this a game bug and am I misunderstanding the stack?
I thought all combat damage was dealt at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: Despite being the computer version of the game, I felt people here much more able to help me with the rules (not game) question.  If this is misposted please let me know.

Comment: Remember there is a difference between combat damage and damage from spells and abilities.

Comment: Regarding your footnote: Rules questions are definitely on topic here. (It is nice to mention that you stumbled upon this situation while playing the digital version, on the off chance that you actually found a bug.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All combat damage is dealt simultaneously. But the damage from Perilous Myr's trigger isn't combat damage, it is an unrelated triggered ability. All combat damage was dealt, which resulted in the Myr dying and your opponent being at 0 health. This also resulted in the Myr's ability triggering, but that trigger never even makes it to the stack, because state-based actions are checked before triggered abilities are added to the stack. When they are checked, your opponent loses for having 0 health.

Comment: I don't think the Perilous Myr will even see the graveyard, since the round of state-based actions that processes lethal damage will be the same one that causes the opponent to lose the game.

Comment: Well, it would be put into the graveyard at the same time that the opponent would lose (all SBAs in a single round are processed simultaneously), but the trigger because no player receives priority before the game ends.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I'm not entirely sure what it means for the myr to be put in the graveyard at the same time as the game ending. I guess it would be more precise to say that there is instance when it is in the graveyard while the game is still active.

Comment: It definitely isn't worth worrying about for the OP, but I guess a time when this distinction would matter is in a multiplayer game if an opponent has something that says "whenever a creature dies" - I think that ability would see the Myr die and trigger?

Comment: @HaoYe It's simultaneous because 704.3 says it is. You're correct that in the case where there are only two players, it doesn't *matter* that it's simultaneous, but that doesn't mean that it isn't. And as Jefromi points out, it can matter if there are more than two players.

Comment: The Perilous Myr dies, going into the graveyard. However, before the ability has a chance to trigger, the game evaluates for State Based actions. Seeing the controlling player at 0 live, everything he or she has is exiled from the game. Even in a multiplayer game, the attacking OP would survive this to see the second main, and the triggered ability doesn't get put onto the stack.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I'm confused what you're trying to add - it sounds like you're simply reiterating the existing answer? The point about multiplayer games isn't that the Myr's trigger happens - it doesn't - it's that *other* abilities from *other* players' permanents could potentially trigger off the Myr dying.